# Posts gathered from WPEMatico feeds are being mixed in different languages. Polylang is used for language separation

Tags: posts, rss, feed, plugin-polylang

I have set up RSS feeds in WPEMatico in different campaigns, each one gathering news in different languages. The campaigns are then connected to different Post Categories, each of which is set up in a specific language and the feeds are turned into posts.

The language differentiation in the website is done through the PolyLang plugin, where each page represents one language and all the posts in that specific language, from their respective category.

The problem is that the posts of different languages are being mixed somehow. Any ideas what the problem might be?

I've checked to make sure that each campaign is set to the right category, and everything is correct. However, somewhere along the way the category is switched, which results in them being posted in the wrong page.